# UIButton Action doesn't call in Swift?

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift2

In my project I have create the Left View and Right View, its dynamically show two different Views, Left View side create firstView and the FirstView inside show Title, Comments, Image and Video. And Also RightView side create secondView inside show Title,Comments, Image and Video. Image and Video show only some of the Views. The design is fully created programmatically, my design is given below,

[image]

**My problem is play button(`UIButton`) Action not Called why?**

**I don't know,
my code is give below, `UIButton` Name: btnPlay, Action Name: buttonAction:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollViewBase: UIScrollView!
    var leftView = UIView()
    var rightView = UIView()

    var wholeYLeft = CGFloat()
    var wholeYRight = CGFloat()
    let btnPlay = UIButton()

    var myArrayOfDict: NSArray = [
        ["Title": "MacBook", "Text": "Our goal with MacBook was to do the impossible: engineer a full-sized experience into the lightest and most compact Mac notebook ever. That meant reimagining every element to make it not only lighter and thinner but also better.", "Image":"MacBook1","video":""],
        ["Title": "OS X", "Text": "OS X is the operating system that makes it possible to do all the things you do on a Mac.", "Image":"","video":""],
        ["Title": "MacBook Pro", "Text": "Now with the force Touch trackpad,longer battery life and faster flash storage", "Image":"MacBookPro1","video":""],
        ["Title": "Mac Mini", "Text": "Mac mini is an affordable powerhouse that packs the entire Mac experience into a 19.7cm-square frame. Just connect your own display, keyboard and mouse, and you’re ready to make big things happen.", "Image":"Mini","video":""],
        ["Title": "iMac", "Text": "The idea behind iMac has never wavered: to craft the ultimate desktop experience. The best display, paired with high-performance processors, graphics and storage ", "Image":"","video":""],
        ["Title": "MacBook Air", "Text": "The 11-inch MacBook Air lasts up to 9 hours between charges and the 13-inch model lasts up to an incredible 12 hours. So from your morning coffee till your evening commute, you can work unplugged.", "Image":"VideoThumn","video":"Official Apple MacBook Air Video YouTube.mp4"]
    ]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.title = "Dynamic Cell"


        leftView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width/2, self.view.frame.height)
        rightView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width/2, 0, self.view.frame.width/2, self.view.frame.height)

//        leftView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
//        rightView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

        self.scrollViewBase.addSubview(leftView)
        self.scrollViewBase.addSubview(rightView)

        self.callViewMethod()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func callViewMethod() {

        var yFloatLeft : CGFloat! = 5

        var yFloatRight : CGFloat! = 5

        wholeYLeft = 0
        wholeYRight = 0

        for var i = 0; i < myArrayOfDict.count; i++ {

            let isCheckImage = myArrayOfDict[i].valueForKey("Image") as! String
            let isCheckVideo = myArrayOfDict[i].valueForKey("video") as! String

            let str = myArrayOfDict[i].valueForKey("Text") as? String

            let boundingRectHeight = str!.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(self.leftView.frame.width-10, CGFloat.max),
                options:NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin,
                attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 14.0)!], context:nil).size.height + 60.0


            if(i%2 == 0) {
                let firstView = UIView()
                print(yFloatLeft)
                if(isCheckImage == "") {
                    firstView.frame = CGRectMake(5, yFloatLeft, self.leftView.frame.width-10, 30 + boundingRectHeight)
                } else {
                    firstView.frame = CGRectMake(5, yFloatLeft, self.leftView.frame.width-10, 180 + boundingRectHeight)
                }

//                firstView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
                firstView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
                firstView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
                leftView.addSubview(firstView)

                let lblTitle = UILabel()
                lblTitle.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.leftView.frame.width-10, 30)
                lblTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
                lblTitle.text = myArrayOfDict[i].valueForKey("Title") as? String

                let lblText = lblInset()
                lblText.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, self.leftView.frame.width-10, boundingRectHeight)
                lblText.text = myArrayOfDict[i].valueForKey("Text") as? String
                lblText.numberOfLines = 0
                lblText.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
                lblText.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 16)
                lblText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Justified

                let mainImageView = UIImageView()

                if(isCheckImage == "") {
                    mainImageView.hidden = true
                    yFloatLeft = yFloatLeft + 30 + boundingRectHeight + 10

                } else {
                    mainImageView.hidden = false
                    mainImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30 + boundingRectHeight, self.leftView.frame.width-10, 150)
                    mainImageView.image = UIImage(named: (myArrayOfDict[i].valueForKey("Image") as? String)!)

                    if(isCheckVideo == "") {
                        btnPlay.hidden = true
                    } else {
                        btnPlay.hidden = false
                        btnPlay.frame = CGRectMake((mainImageView.frame.width/2)-10, (mainImageView.frame.height/2)-10, 30, 30)
                        btnPlay.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                        btnPlay.userInteractionEnabled = true
                        btnPlay.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
                        btnPlay.setImage(UIImage(named: "Play"), forState: .Normal)
                        mainImageView.addSubview(btnPlay)

                    }
                    yFloatLeft = yFloatLeft + 30 + boundingRectHeight + 160
                }


                firstView.addSubview(lblTitle)
                firstView.addSubview(lblText)
                firstView.addSubview(mainImageView)
                firstView.bringSubviewToFront(btnPlay)

            } else {
                let secondView = UIView()
                if(isCheckImage == "") {
                    secondView.frame = CGRectMake(5, yFloatRight, self.rightView.frame.width-10, 30 + boundingRectHeight)
                } else {
                    secondView.frame = CGRectMake(5, yFloatRight, self.rightView.frame.width-10, 180 + boundingRectHeight)
                }

//                secondView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
                secondView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
                secondView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
                rightView.addSubview(secondView)

                let lblTitle = UILabel()
                lblTitle.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.leftView.frame.width-10, 30)
                lblTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
                lblTitle.text = myArrayOfDict[i].valueForKey("Title") as? String

                let lblText = lblInset()
                lblText.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, self.leftView.frame.width-10, boundingRectHeight)
                lblText.text = myArrayOfDict[i].valueForKey("Text") as? String
                lblText.numberOfLines = 0
                lblText.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
                lblText.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 16)
                lblText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Justified

                let mainImageView = UIImageView()

                if(isCheckImage == "") {
                    mainImageView.hidden = true
                    yFloatRight = yFloatRight + 30 + boundingRectHeight + 10

                } else {
                    mainImageView.hidden = false
                    mainImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30 + boundingRectHeight, self.leftView.frame.width-10, 150)
                    mainImageView.image = UIImage(named: (myArrayOfDict[i].valueForKey("Image") as? String)!)

                    if(isCheckVideo == "") {
                        btnPlay.hidden = true
                    } else {
                        btnPlay.hidden = false
                        btnPlay.frame = CGRectMake((mainImageView.frame.width/2)-10, (mainImageView.frame.height/2)-10, 30, 30)
                        btnPlay.userInteractionEnabled = true
                        btnPlay.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                        btnPlay.setImage(UIImage(named: "Play"), forState: .Normal)
                        btnPlay.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonAction:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
                        mainImageView.addSubview(btnPlay)
                    }


                    yFloatRight = yFloatRight + 30 + boundingRectHeight + 160
                }


                secondView.addSubview(lblTitle)
                secondView.addSubview(lblText)
                secondView.addSubview(mainImageView)
                secondView.bringSubviewToFront(btnPlay)

            }

            wholeYLeft = yFloatLeft
            wholeYRight = yFloatRight
        }
        print(wholeYLeft)
        print(wholeYRight)
        leftView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width/2, wholeYLeft)
        rightView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width/2, 0, self.view.frame.width/2, wholeYRight)

        if(wholeYRight > wholeYLeft) {
            self.scrollViewBase.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.view.frame.width, height: wholeYRight)
        } else {
            self.scrollViewBase.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.view.frame.width, height: wholeYLeft)
        }

    }

    func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PlayViewController") as! PlayViewController

        controller.lblTitle.text = myArrayOfDict[5].valueForKey("Title") as? String
        controller.lblComments.text = myArrayOfDict[5].valueForKey("Text") as? String

        self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: i am doing something similar. What is lblInset in your code?

Comment: its custom class for `UILabel`

Comment: great. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an Answer, In `UIButton` (btnPlay) add subview give `UIImageView`, my problem is `mainImageView.addSubview(btnPlay)`, so change the subView to `UIView` instead of `UIImageView` correct code is

```
secondView.addSubview(btnPlay)
secondView.bringSubviewToFront(btnPlay)
```

its working for me

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable user interaction for dynamically created Imageview, so write one more line after,

```
let mainImageView = UIImageView()
mainImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: I have already give `userInteractionEnabled` but its not called

Comment: Ok. But you had given it to UIButton. This is for imageView

Answer (score 0):

You have to **tag** the button then only it can recognise which button is that

```
btnPlay.tag = 1
```